# PHP - try and catch block (Exception) handling

Tags: php, exception, try-catch

I'm in doubt about exception handling.

If I have a function `foo();` is it same as if I handle it like this:

```
try {
    foo();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    // do someting
}
```

or if I do it in function like this:

```
foo() {
    try {
       // function body
    } catch (Exception $e) {
       // do someting
    }
}
```

And what if I do not throw `Exception` ? Code will continue to execute even if error appears ?

Comment: the `catch` will only execute if an `exception` has been fired from your `try` block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, code will continue. In php exists errors and exceptions. You can handle errors with function `set_error_handler()`, handle uncathable exceptions with function `set_exception_handler()` and you can handle exceptions using `try .. catch`